# Access Records/Rows disappearing from lookup table

Tags: ms-access, lookup-tables

Access 2013

I have a simple lookup table that twice in the last month a record (different record on each occasion) has disappeared.

Since the auto id of the table is used as the foreign key I am forced to drop the table and recreate it.

I don't provide any delete functionality at all to users in the Access DB and especially not to the lookup table.

I have done a global search for all references to the table in my VBA code and found it was used several times but only in select statements.

At the moment I suspect a user is fiddling with something they don't fully understand and they are inadvertently deleting the record.

What else can I do determine the cause of this problem?

Can I make the lookup table read only?

Comment: I managed to reproduce the delete on the lookup table without ever issuing a delete!!!   When I go to the datasheet view of my form and manually delete a record the associated record from the lookup table is also deleted. Why?

Comment: You can add a Data Macro to prevent record deletions, but if a user is sufficiently knowledgeable about Access, this mechanism can be circumvented.

Comment: Is the lookup table static or nearly so?  You could change the auto number field to a normal field so that you could easily rebuild it via code or from a "backup template" version of the table.  Also, you can actually set Auto Number field to specific values using VBA code and Database.Execute and a an SQL `INSERT INTO` statement.  The Access interface does not allow it, but the Jet/Ace database engine does.

Comment: If you use an `INSERT INTO` action to create record for specific autonumber value, be sure to run Compact and Repair immediately after so the autonumber seed will reset correctly. Do your users have access to the tables or table links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a second lookup table that had a temporary relationship defined in the query that was not required. i.e: no columns were based upon this unnecessary table.  This unnecessary lookup table was simply being used as a row source for a combobox on the form.

I discovered this after I noticed the form data type was set to Dynaset (Inconsistent Updates).  Why?  When I tested the form with normal Dynaset the form refused to perform any updates!

When I removed the unnecessary lookup table from the query I was able to set the data type back to Dynaset with updates continuing to work and deletions no longer cascading through to my first and required lookup table.

In addition the unnecessary lookup table was actually a query that was referencing a table in another database.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the relationships window. Look at the linked tables in question and see if there is a 'Cascade Deletes' checked. If so, deleting one record will delete related records.

Comment: Don't think so the relationship is temporary to the query and has not been defined in relationships.

Comment: I think you were pretty close to the answer. See my resolution!